Defining the k-path in a tbtrans calculation
The TBtrans manual mentions the possibility of defining a k-path for calculating transport properties:
path: Defines a Brillouin zone path with equi-spaced k-points. For example:
path 10
from 0.0 0.0 0.0
to 0.5 0.5 0.0
path 20
from 0.25 0.25 0.0
to 0.0 0.5 0.0
This creates k-points starting from the Γ-point and moves to the Brillouin zone boundary at [1/2, 1/2, 0], with 10 points along this path. Paths do not need to be continuous, and multiple paths can be specified.
However, I’m unclear on how to incorporate this into the input .fdf file. I’ve tried several flags, but none have worked.
Thank you in advance for your response.
